# Pyflakes + pep8 check on vim in normal mode

Tags: python, vim, pep8, pyflakes

I use vim as my IDE with python and it's been great. I use pyflakes + pep8 with
the appropriate plugin. I need these additional features:

1. pyflakes check "on the fly" *without* having to switch to normal mode.
2. pep8 check "on the fly". Currently, I have mapped 'F6' to do pep8 check and
   a quickfix window pops up. I want pep8 to be done the same way as pyflakes, but
   in normal mode.
3. Highlights for pep8 and pyflakes must be different.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Checking with `pyflakes` on the fly

- [pyflakes-pathogen](http://www.github.com/mitechie/pyflakes-pathogen) lets you check on the fly (same as [pyflakes](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441) but works with pathogen).

#### You can autorun pep8+pyflakes on write with `flake8`

- [flake8](https://www.github.com/nvie/vim-flake8) can highlight pep8 and pyflakes errors on write. (possibly on the fly?). Plus, you can set a list of errors to ignore (for example, the pep8 error about how to define variable names).

Unfortunately, I don't know if anyone's written a pep8 checker on the fly. Maybe not enough demand?